# confused on to leave in centimeters or convert to cubic centimeters

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, volume

The volume $V$ of the cylinder is $65\pi \mathrm{cm}^3$. The height of the cylinder is $5$ centimeters. Use the formula $V = Bh$ to find the area of the base of the cylinder.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

$B$ is measured in $\mathrm{cm}^2$, $h$ - in $\mathrm{cm}$, and $V = B \times h$ in $\mathrm{cm}^2 \times \mathrm{cm} = \mathrm{cm}^3$...

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  An area is always square centimeters.  You need to respect [dimensional homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Dimensional_homogeneity), so if you divide a volume (cm^3) by a length (cm) you have an area (cm^2)